How to use the Features of type "Object" in Linear regression model
I'm very new in this domain. I have a dataset that looks something like the below;
Columns: Make. Model. Year. Km driven. Price
Data Type: object. object. int64. int64. int64.
I am trying to fit the data into the Linear Regression model. First, I used each column/feature to find the predicted price and made a scatter plot of the price and predicted price which went well when the feature type is int. My question is, once I try to fit data in the Linear Regression model, I can't. As linear Regression is associating any numerical (or binary, which is a particular numerical) value to a coefficient. My question is, how can we use those Object type features in the Linear Regression model?
Should we convert these object features to Numerics? Like - Car Brand A = 10, Car Brand B = 20. Is it a scalable way? Or there is a better way to achieve this?
Let's consider, we are predicting a pre-owned car price. Thanks in advance.

There are several different ways of using text/categorical features in a machine learning model, such as one hot encoding, ordinal encoding, or even using text embeddings.
